# Is it possible, with bitcoin-core or btcd, to manually set the scriptSig field in a coinbase transaction?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-reward, coinbase-transaction, input-script, btcd

I am talking about when using regtest or simnet modes.

For context, it is so that I can create coinbase transactions with reproducible txids.

Comment: By "reproducible txids" do you mean that you want to know the txid before the transaction is created, or you want the same coinbase txid in multiple blocks?

Comment: I want to be able to start the blockchain from scratch, mine a block with just one coinbase transaction that has a specific scriptSig and address, so that it will produce the same txid each time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in Bitcoin Core. If you want to have control over the coinbase transaction, you will need to use external mining software that allows you to do that.

Since the difficulty on regtest is so low, you could have a simple python script that produces blocks with your specific coinbase. You don't need actual mining software as the difficulty is low enough to be found almost instantaneously with a naive mining implementation.